# Facebook SDK 4.0.0, ShareDialog on Android is always null

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I want to share something on Facebook using its SDK. My reference is [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#share_dialog) by Facebook based on Facebook SDK 4.0.0.

```
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
        ShareDialog shareDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.getWindow().addFlags(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.v3_activity_splash);

            // Init Facebook SDK
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
            shareOnFacebook("This is test...");

            ...
        }

    private void shareOnFacebook(String content)
    {
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))
        {
            Log.e("Test", "inside shareOnFacebook()");

            //            ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentDescription(content).build();
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                    .setContentDescription(content)
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NOT CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e("Test", "Yes, Uuu bitch!!!");
    }
```

I also have following lines of code in my manifest file within `Application` tag:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="MY_APP_ID"/>

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMY_APP_ID"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

My problem is NullPointerException when I launch the app/activity on `shareDialog.show(linkContent);` line. However, funny thing is `shareDialog` is not null based on my debug :( So have no idea why "NullPointerException" throws. I also don't see my log of `onActivityResult` therefore this function does not get called.

[image]

Finally Log shows:

```
Process: MY_PCKAGE_NAME, PID: 2152
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MY_PCKAGE_NAME/MY_PCKAGE_NAME.v3.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:883)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getDialogFeatureConfig(Utility.java:859)
            at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getVersionSpecForFeature(DialogPresenter.java:247)
            at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getProtocolVersionForNativeDialog(DialogPresenter.java:234)
            at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.canPresentNativeDialogWithFeature(DialogPresenter.java:75)
            at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.canShowNative(ShareDialog.java:133)
            at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.access$300(ShareDialog.java:55)
            at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:241)
            at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:233)
            at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.createAppCallForMode(FacebookDialogBase.java:184)
            at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.showImpl(FacebookDialogBase.java:147)
            at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.show(FacebookDialogBase.java:142)
            at MY_PCKAGE_NAME.splash.SplashActivity.shareOnFacebook(SplashActivity.java:414)
            at MY_PCKAGE_NAME.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:93)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just created a sample project to find where is my problem and finally found I had two mistakes. Actually one of them is not because of me, Facebook is crazy!

1) I forgot to add Facebook activity into my manifest file (That's why I didn't get log of `OnActivityResult`)

```
<!-- Facebook -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

2) You ***MUST*** create `facebook_app_id` inside your strings.xml file and link meta-data to that instead of directly put your app_id there.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

After these changes I'm able to see Facebook dialog in my project.
These things wasted TWO days of mine and hope doesn't happen to you.

Comment: I added FacebookActivity, meta-data and provider in manifeset and also used string resource to hold FB_app_id value which I only used in meta tag and actual id in provider tag, but still have same error. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @crwler if above two items are correct make sure hashcode you have generated is okay too. My suggestion is use their sample code to generate one otherwise if you generate based on command then it always create one regardless of right or wrong command.

Comment: I had this issue and from your comment I then looked into the source a bit more and there's a fun bit in the Facebook SDK initialization.
You either have to link to string resource, or prefix the id with 'fb'. So:

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb1234567890"/>

Basically, the code needs the property value to be a String. If you just enter your ID it obviously gets typed as an int. They actually throw an exception if they find the value but it's an int instead of just handling it. I'd guess it's future-proofed in case they want alpha codes later.